# Python - Make class return object if sub object is not defined

Tags: python, class

I'm not sure if Python allows anything like what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I'm trying to assign a default object to a class so that if you reference the class directly, it returns that object, otherwise it accesses the sub objects of the class.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in code:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     a = 0
...     b = 1
...     def __new__(cls):
...         return 2

>>> obj = MyClass()

>>> # I want it to print 0
>>> print obj.a
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'

>>> # I want it to print 1
>>> print obj.b
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'b'

>>> # I want it to print 2
>>> print obj
2
```

Comment: You can do things that visually look like what you want for the `print` statements, but "assign a default object to a class so that if you reference the class directly, it returns that object" doesn't make sense in Python's evaluation model.

Comment: `MyClass.__new__` simply isn't returning an instance of `MyClass`; it's just returning an instance of `int`, namely `2`. Being returned by `MyClass.__new__` doesn't magically change what `2` is.

Comment: You might also want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `int` instead:

```
class MyClass(int):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, value)
```

so that:

```
obj = MyClass(2)
print(obj.a)
print(obj.b)
print(obj)
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with a method instead of an integer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by doing this with a method. Do you mean that you want `__new__` to return an object of a custom class? Can you show the use case?